# How to build CUDA 4.0 samples with Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, cuda, nvidia, gpu

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and want to build the examples under C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA 4.0 GPU Computing Toolkit\C\src.

I had lots of problems regarding include files, but they are partly solved by building the cutil project under C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK 4.0\C\common using Visual Studio.

But when I try to compile the nbody example, I get an error message which implies a conflict with previously installed 3.2 GPU Computing Toolkit.

How can I fix this "exit with -1" error?

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\BuildCustomizations\CUDA
>   4.0.targets(357,9): error MSB3721: The command ""C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v3.2\bin\nvcc.exe"
>   -gencode=arch=compute_10,code=\"sm_10,compute_10\" -gencode=arch=compute_20,code=\"sm_20,compute_20\" --use-local-env --cl-version 2010 -ccbin "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin" -I"./" -I"../../common/inc"
>   -I"../../../shared/inc" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v3.2\include"  -G0  --keep-dir "Debug" -maxrregcount=0 
>   --machine 32 --compile  -D_NEXUS_DEBUG -g    -Xcompiler "/EHsc /nologo /Od /Zi  /MTd " -o "Win32/Debug/bodysystemcuda.cu.obj"
>   "C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK
>   4.0\C\src\nbody\bodysystemcuda.cu"" exited with code -1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have the 3.2 include directory in the path instead of the 4.0  what is CUDA_INC_PATH set to ?